# best approach for testing javascript UI with jasmine

Tags: javascript, selenium, tdd, jasmine

I was having a first look at the jasmine framework and it looks really promising, but I couldn't find an easy way to work with the dom.

I mean, simulating user interaction, like completing and input, clicking a button, and then checking that the dom is correctly updated, like showing errors after input validation, and showing the modified data. Just the kind of stuff you usually do with tools like selenium.

Is there a standard way to do it or is ui testing out of jasmine's domain and I should look for another framework for such a a task?

Comment: Have you looked at Selenium? I noticed you tagged this question with the tag but just seem to be asking about Jasmine.

Comment: I did acouple of things with selenium, but I thought that jasmine would be enough, I try not to add yet another framework to the mix

Comment: selenium really has little to do with the js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) is what most people use for testing UI with jasmine. It allows you to create sandbox fixtures to run your tests upon while defining most of the matchers you will need. It's pretty straight-forward and even if you do not rely on jQuery in your app, will work fine for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the new kid on the block
https://github.com/tigbro/jasmine-ui

Comment: Actually, jasmine-ui has been moved to uitests.js: https://github.com/opitzconsulting/uitest.js

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at DalekJS (still in alpha) :

[Automated Cross-browser UI testing](http://dalekjs.com/index.html)

Comment: From DalekJS' website: `* DalekJS is currently a developer preview. Some features are missing, some things might change, there's a lot of optimisation to be done. Don't use this for production!`

Comment: That is why I didn't say 'hey look here this is going to do everything, and will never crash'. I said that he should take a look. Check it out. Try it out. Maybe it does suits his needs, as it did suit mine

Comment: Still a pretty big caveat that would help people coming here, so that some people don't waste their time looking at it (like I did) because its not production ready.

Comment: I updated the answer so that very busy people won't waste too much seconds

Comment: Project looks dead at this point

Comment: yep indeed it does

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for a perfect solution for me, but the article [E2E Testing With WebDriverJS and Jasmine](http://engineering.wingify.com/posts/e2e-testing-with-webdriverjs-jasmine/) looks like to give a really good approach to use Jasmine with Selenium.